# Looping through with List<WebElement> with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I get a list of anchors using the code below, and then I want to go to each link. I have came up with the code below, but after the first loop I get the following exception

> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element
>   reference: element is not attached to the page document   (Session
>   info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)

```
List<WebElement> listingAnchorList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'cat')]/a"));

for (WebElement listingAnchor : listingAnchorList) {
    driver.get(listingAnchor.getAttribute("href"));
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
}
```

Is there anyway to do this without having go to back to the page every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect your `href` attributes in some new `List`, and then iterate over it and open each page.